# ARM assembly print register value in decimal

Tags: printing, decimal, arm

I have an exponentiation subroutine that does the calculation and puts the result in r0. Currently I can print the result in hexadecimal, but I also want to print it in decimal. After doing a lot of searching online I haven't found a straightforward way of doing it. Seems like a simple task to do but I can't figure it out.

thanks

Comment: Usually formatting to decimal should be easier than to hex (if you do it manually). In the simplest case you just replace one `16` with `10`.

Comment: @Joachim: decimal is quite a bit harder. Hex digits can be extracted in order using shift and mask operations. Decimal digits require either division by powers of 10, or repeated division by 10 (which gives them in reverse order).

Comment: octal is easier than hex because you dont have the if greater than nine then add 7, hex is easy, decimal is hard you have to divide by 10 essentially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm tempted to say "link with a C library and call printf". If that's not an option, here is something that probably works, given a "putchar" function that outputs the ASCII character in r0. It repeatedly divides the number by 10, writing the digits into a small buffer on the stack, then outputs them in reverse order. It requires architecture 4M or better for the "umull" instruction.

```
print_decimal:
        stmfd   sp!, {r4,r5,lr}

        cmp     r0, #0
        moveq   r0, #'0'
        bleq    putchar
        beq     done

        mov     r4, sp
        mov     r5, sp
        sub     sp, sp, #12

        rsblt   r0, r0, #0          ; r0 = abs(r0)
        movlt   lr, #1              ; lr = negative ? 1 : 0
        movgt   lr, #0

        ldr     r1, =0x1999999a     ; r1 = 2^32 / 10

loop:   umull   r2, r3, r0, r1      ; r3 = r0 / 10
        sub     r2, r0, r3, lsl #3
        sub     r2, r2, r3, lsl #1  ; r2 = r0 - 10*r3 = r0 % 10

        add     r2, r2, #'0'
        strb    r2, [r4, #-1]!

        movs    r0, r3
        bne     loop

        cmp     lr, #0
        movne   r0, #'-'
        blne    putchar

write:  ldrb    r0, [r4], #1
        bl      putchar
        cmp     r4, r5
        blt     write

        add     sp, sp, #12
done:
        ldmfd   sp!, {r4,r5,lr}
        mov     r0, #'\n'
        b       putchar
```